# Codeigniter Insert Data MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, codeigniter-3, sql-insert

I am working website with multiple database and it use both MSSQL and MYSQL but I don`t why insert data won`t work. I have 2 codes sample below:

1st MODEL code

```
$this->mssqlu->insert('tbl_account', array('id ' => CONVERT(BINARY(16),$username, 1), 'password' => CONVERT(BINARY(16),$password, 1), 'Email' => $email, 'accounttype' =>0, 'birthdate' => '2011-11-11 00:00:00','pin' => $pin, 'fb_id' => $fb_id ));
    return $this->mssqlu->insert_id();
```

2nd MODEL Code

```
 $lu_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_account (id,password,Email,accounttype,birthdate,pin,fb_id) VALUES ((CONVERT (binary,$username)),(CONVERT (binary,$password)),$email,0,'2011-11-11 00:00:00',$pin,$fb_id)");
    $query = $this->mssqlu->query($lu_sql);
    return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data=array('id ' => CONVERT(BINARY(16),$username, 1), 'password' => 
              CONVERT(BINARY(16),$password, 1), 'Email' => $email, 'accounttype' 
             =>0,'birthdate' => '2011-11-11 00:00:00','pin' => $pin, 'fb_id' => 
             $fb_id );
```

return (($this->mssqlu->insert('tbl_account', $data)) ? $this->mssqlu->insert_id() : False);